# Конвертер длины и расстояния

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qpushbutton

Недавно начал изучение языка *Python*, в частности *PyQt5*. 
По задумке это должен быть конвертер единиц длины.

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на `QPushButton` ("*Конвертировать*")  приложение просто закрывается.
Довольно долго искал решение данной проблемы, но все в пустую.

**converter.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(650, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.inpNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inpNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 150, 50))
        self.inpNum.setObjectName("inpNum")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 30, 81, 51))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 30, 81, 51))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(222, 117, 181, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.outNum = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.outNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 30, 131, 51))
        self.outNum.setText("")
        self.outNum.setObjectName("outNum")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 650, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "км"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "см"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "мм"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "км"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "см"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "мм"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конвертировать"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```py
import sys
from converter import *


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated1)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated2)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getResult)

    def onActivated1(self, text):
        self.inn = text

    def onActivated2(self, text):
        self.outt = text

    def getResult(self, text):
        try:
            n1 = self.ui.inpNum.text()
            answer = convert_len(n1)
            self.ui.outNum.setText(str(answer))
        except:
            msg = QtWidgets.QmessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("output error")
            msg.setText("input correct data")
            msg.setIcon(msg.Warning)
            msg.exec()

    def convert_len(self, n1):
        op = {'мм': 0.001, 'см': 0.01, 'м': 1.0, 'км': 1000.}
        return n1 * op[self.inn] / op[self.outt]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отметил для вас проблемные строки кода. Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from converter import Ui_MainWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(650, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.inpNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inpNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 150, 50))
        self.inpNum.setObjectName("inpNum")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 30, 81, 51))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 30, 81, 51))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(222, 117, 181, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.outNum = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.outNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 30, 131, 51))
        self.outNum.setText("")
        self.outNum.setObjectName("outNum")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 650, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "км"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "см"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "мм"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "км"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "м"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "см"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "мм"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Конвертировать"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.inn  = "км"                                                    # +++
        self.outt = "км"                                                    # +++

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated1)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated2)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getResult)

    def onActivated1(self, text):
        self.inn = text

    def onActivated2(self, text):
        self.outt = text

    def getResult(self): #, text):
#    try:
        n1 = self.ui.inpNum.text()
        if n1:       
            answer = self.convert_len(n1)                                  # self.
            self.ui.outNum.setText(str(answer))
#    except:
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()                                  # QmessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("output error")
            msg.setText("Введите числовое значение для конвертации.")
            msg.setIcon(msg.Warning)
            msg.exec()

    def convert_len(self, n1):
        op = {'мм': 0.001, 'см': 0.01, 'м': 1.0, 'км': 1000.}
        return int(n1) * op[self.inn] / op[self.outt]                      # int(n1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает.  Но я бы оставил конструкцию try/except, чтобы при вводе чего-либо кроме числа, выскакивало окошко с ошибкой, и программа не зависала.